# Ridge regression, why do we need $I$ in $\beta = (Z^T Z+\lambda I)^{-1} Z^T y$

Tags: linear-algebra

Penalized residual sum of squares of ridge regression is:

$(y-Z\beta)^T(y-Z\beta)+\lambda ||\beta||_2^2$

If I take a derivative wrt to $\beta$ of the above, I obtain:

$-2Z^T(y-Z\beta)+2\lambda \beta$

I need to minimize the above, since it is a convex function, there is a unique solution, so:

$-2Z^T(y-Z\beta)+2\lambda \beta=0$

Then I obtain:

$\beta = (Z^T Z+\lambda)^{-1} Z^T y$

However, the notes indicate that I need identity matrix multiplied by lambda. Now my linear algebra is not particularly strong, but I know that identity matrix does not change whatever you multiply it with. So would that mean that my solution is equivalent to the one in the notes? In which case, why do they include an identity matrix in there?

Comment: To me, $Z^T Z+\lambda$ indicates adding $\lambda$ to *every* element of $Z^T Z$, and $Z^T Z+\lambda I$ only to the *diagonal* elements.

Comment: Yes. So the solutions are different then.. Why is that the case..

Comment: The identity matrix is a matrix with ones all along the diagonal and zero everywhere else. To multiply with $\beta$ on each position of the vector would be the same to multiply with $\beta I$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we need to take it step by step

$-2Z^T(y-Z\beta)+2\lambda \beta = 0$

$-2Z^Ty + 2Z^TZ\beta + 2\lambda\beta = 0$

$2Z^TZ\beta + 2\lambda\beta = 2Z^Ty$

Now when you factor the left hand side and know that $\lambda$ is a scalar and $\beta$ is a vector, the only matrix which can give element wise multiplication like that is $\lambda I$.